# Which demographic of English speakers say "I've to" for "I have to"?

Tags: contractions, dialects

In a forum I frequent there are many times that contractions are used in a way that's unusual, and many users find to be ungrammatical:

**"I've to"** etc.

To me it's not ungrammatical but it sounds both old-fashioned and like something you might hear in certain rural areas of England, but I don't know where.

Do some of our English experts here have more information on who uses or used this structure? Which region or regions and which age groups etc?

Comment: It is not something that I associate with any particular region of Britain, nor to say that it is more associated with e.g. "the north". But I think it has become dated. I don't think it is heard as much as it once was. But that's just my subjective impression.

Comment: I'd say 'I've to be at the station by 11' sounds less unnatural than 'I've to bleed the radiators before the central heating engineer comes on Thursday'.

Comment: I would say 'I've got to' is more idiomatic than 'I've to'. Ngram indicates similar - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+to%2CI%27ve+got+to%2CI%27ve+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ve%20got%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ve%20to%3B%2Cc0 (Link is playing up - click on 'search') I have heard 'I've to' but it is very rare and I cannot remember where I have heard it.

Comment: I've never heard it spoken; it's unknown in the US, where the _have_ of _have to_ is stressed, and thus not contracted. My guess would be that the forums you refer to are full of non-native speakers who are following "rules" they were taught by non-native teachers. There's a great deal of that around, as anyone can tell by looking at the questions posted here.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes there are both native and non-native speakers on the forum for sure, but I expect there are also young people who haven't been exposed to as much regional variation or as much English as it was used in the past.

Comment: @JohnLawler  It certainly was idiomatic to native British speakers, as evidenced by the fact that both Edwin and I recognised it.  But then both he and I are fairly "long in the tooth". It also extended to such as "He's to see his aunt on Sunday". But that means "He is to..."

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have any evidence past my own experience but I am 28 and I lived in the South of England until I was 18 and then moved to Scotland. I have heard "I've to" infrequently in England and never in Scotland. I would personally associate it with old fashioned but informal language.

Comment: adding your research  makes your answer better.  Without it may be further reviewed